# SubString not working properly within a for loop in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to read a text file "data.txt" which contains some data in the given format:

```
data = 12 39 43 45 05 32 77 34 87 93 72 21 04 23 03 12 06 11 15 32 12 14 05 15 17 15 29 33 15
```

first I need to extract only the data next to the string `data =` and then process this data in the following manner:

-Parse fifth element and multiply it with a constant `3` to sub-string the whole string by the result of the multiplication. For example: in the above data, fifth element is `5` so I need to sub-string `15` characters starting from `32` until `93`,  write them to text file and then override the current data with data after `93` and so on..

The code works fine without the for loop but when I need the loop to update the variables and process more than one iteration it keeps parsing same data every time.

Can you please advise ?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS EnableDelayedExpansion

REM Exclude "data=" from the text
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%B in ('findstr /I "data = " data.txt') do (
set "Current_data=%%B" 
)
for /L %%s IN (1,1,2) do (

REM each time parse 5th element 
echo old=!Current_data!
 for /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I in ("!Current_data!") do (
 set /a "inew=%%I"
 echo inew = !inew!
)

REM Calculate shift needed and next position based on 5th element parsed
 Set /a "initial_pos=16"
 Set /a "_shift=!inew!*3"
 echo _shift=!_shift!
Set /a next_pos=!initial_pos!+!_shift!
echo next_pos=!next_pos!

REM Parse data
 Set parsed_data=!Current_data:~%initial_pos%,%_shift%!
 echo parsed_data=!parsed_data!

REM Override "Current_data" with the remaining data after sub-stringing "parsed_data"
Set Current_data=!Current_data:~%next_pos%!
echo Current_data=!Current_data!
)
endlocal
```

Comment: It is important to note, given the provided data and your use of `Set /A` that you may very well have problems with certain elements, `08` or `09` for instance, which would be seen as octal. I would suggest you design a workaround for such possibilities.

Comment: Compo,I'm sorry I didn't take a notice but I've already commented down on another answer that using labels and using the findstr arguments recommended ( /BIL) did absolutely solve my problem.
Separately, my intention in the example above was to find the fifth element which is 5 above multiply by 3 which is the separation factor between each element store the result in the variable "_shift" which then i will use to sub-string the following 5 elements 32 77 34 87 93 and store them. Then the new "current data" will be the string from 72 to the end, find the 5th element and process and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the WHOEL process live inside your First For Loop.  Otherwise, it will only ever find the last instance of data=.

```
REM Exclude "data=" from the text
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%B in ('findstr /I "data = " data.txt') do (
set "Current_data=%%B" 
)
```

The Quickest way to handle this and keep sane is to turn the original portion of your script into a function called from within the loop.  You can re-work the loops and make it into a smaller tighter code too which would run a little faster, but doing the functions makes the code easier to read and change later if needed.

### SO the original script becomes slightly re-written as:

```
@(SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo off
  SET "_SrcFilePath=C:\Path\To\data.txt"
)

CALL :Main

( ENDLOCAL
  Exit /b
)

:Main
  REM Exclude "data=" from the text
  for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%B in ('findstr /I "data = " "%_SrcFilePath%"') do (
    SET "Current_data=%%B"
    CALL :Process
  )
GOTO :EOF 

:Process
  for /L %%s IN (1,1,2) do (
  REM each time parse 5th element 
  echo old=!Current_data!
    for /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%I in ("!Current_data!") do (
    set /a "inew=%%I"
    echo inew = !inew!
  )

    REM Calculate shift needed and next position based on 5th element parsed
    Set /a "initial_pos=16"
    Set /a "_shift=!inew!*3"
    echo _shift=!_shift!
    Set /a next_pos=!initial_pos!+!_shift!
    echo next_pos=!next_pos!

    REM Parse data
    Set parsed_data=!Current_data:~%initial_pos%,%_shift%!
    echo parsed_data=!parsed_data!

    REM Override "Current_data" with the remaining data after sub-stringing "parsed_data"
    Set Current_data=!Current_data:~%next_pos%!
    echo Current_data=!Current_data!
  )
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I've tried it this way but findstr doesn't seem to work.
I've tried to add "set" before defining "_SrcFilePath". This way it worked but still back to the main problem that each iteration of the for loop it types same initial data and doesn't process further.

Comment: That's because this answer uses the same incorrect `findstr` options as your initial question did. To find out how the command works, open a Command Prompt window and enter `findstr /?` where you'll see that `findstr /I "data = "` searches for all lines containing the string `data` and all lines containing the character `=`. You should use either the `/L` option, _(preferred)_, or the `/C` option and you may wish to include with it the `/B` option too, `FindStr /BIL "data = "` would perhaps be more like it!

Comment: @Compo Good find!  Thanks! I looked at this just before heading to bed and only addressed the stated problem so I didn't notice his issue there too.  I suppose I misunderstood, in that I thought he had been using that to set the value before but needed it to loop, whereas I ssume he had been manually setting that value before.  However I will admit I noticed the issue with the leading 0s and decided it wasn't a problem per-se that needed to be addressed if he was happy with it as stood, but I agree it should work incorrectly for the values that hit there but it's also easily fixable.

Comment: @SG229 Okay I only tried to fix the over-arching problem as I understood it, the issue cam ein as I was headed to bed.. as Compo pointed out there are other flaws (some I noticed last night, and some I had not) that were not addressed on initial review as I thought the rest of the code had been 'good enough' and you might just need help with restructuring it.  I'll take a look through and address in more detail betwene other things today.

Comment: Changing `set /a "inew=%%I"` to `set /a "inew=1%%I-100"` solves a problem with invalid octal numbers (`08` and `09`)

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Adding a label before the set variables and calling it from the for loop did it!
Also, did the recommendation for the findstr options and worked perfectly.